# Bootstrap form showing error messages in a different style

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I have two forms in my django app, and I'm using bootstrap3 to custom them, But the error messages to the form aren't equal.

It all is in portuguese

[image]

My templates are using the same structure, I don't know why the difference.

**login.html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <form method="POST" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form form %}
                <input class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" value="Logar">
            </form></br></br>


    </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

---

**signup.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
 <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        <input class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
    </form>
     </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

---

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import User
from django import forms


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("username","email", "password1","password2")
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label = "Usuário"
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email"
        self.fields["password2"].help_text = None
        #self.fields["email"].widget.attrs['readonly']=True

    def clean_email(self):

        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        try:
            u = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email já em uso')
    # return self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()


class UserLogin(AuthenticationForm):

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    ("Email ou Senha errados"))
            elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError(("This account is inactive."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

---

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Static Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

    {% include 'header_css.html' %}



  </head>

  <body>
  {% include 'navbar.html' %}

    {% block jumbotron %}
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        {% block jumbotron_content %}
        {% endblock %}
      </div>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}


    </div> <!-- /container -->
     {% endblock jumbotron %}

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first screenshot is applying the error message to the entire form, (`NON_FIELD_ERRORS`), the second looks like it is applying the errors to the individual fields themselves. In the screenshot on the left the error text is being printed at the top because the error has been applied to the whole form, not a specific field.

In `UserCreateForm` you are applying the error to the `email` field by validating in the `clean_email` method. In `UserLogin` it is a general `clean`.

Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

You could use the `add_error` method to specify the field you want the error to, to replicate the right hand screenshot, or `add_error(None,...` to replicate the formatting on the left (or just use `clean` instead of `clean_email`).

See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like signup.html and login.html pages are using different bootstrap styles (probably one file is still in cache).

Have you tried "hard refresh" in your browser (CTRL + clicking on refresh button in Chrome, CTRL + F5 in Firefox)?

Comment: They using the same style, I edited my post with the original imagens of my forms, unfortunately refreshing the page didn't work, but even so, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your forms.py and base.html ?